# Regex. Find paragraph containing some word

Tags: javascript, regex

In text like this:

`<p>1 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>2 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>3 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>4 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>5 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p>`

I have to find paragraphs (between `p` tags) that contain string "TEXT".
I [tried](https://regex101.com/r/OHnQtG/1/) `<p>.*?(TEXT).*?<\/p>`
and I [tried](https://regex101.com/r/q6eMni/1) `<p>(?!<p>).*?(TEXT).*?<\/p>`

But it doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((?!<\/p>).)*(TEXT)` to make sure 'Text' in one `<p></p>`

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/udf8OH/1)

```js
var regex = /<p>((?!<\/p>).)*?(TEXT).*?<\/p>/g;
var text = '<p>1 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>2 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>3 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>4 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>5 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p>';
console.log(text.match(regex));
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a string, (said by @Rajesh), just create a `div` element and appent to it.

get All the `p` tags using `querySelectorAll` and then use `forEach` function.

Check the `innerHTML` for `/TEXT/` and if found, push it into array.

In the below program, the array `a` contains the 2 matching tags

```js
var str="<p>1 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>2 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>3 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>4 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>5 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p>";
var div=document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=str;
var a=[];
div.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(x=>{if(/TEXT/.test(x.innerHTML)) a.push(x);});
console.log(a);
```

If you don't want the `<p></p>` tags, just push the `textContent`

```js
var str="<p>1 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>2 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>3 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>4 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>5 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p>";
var div=document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=str;
var a=[];
div.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(x=>{if(/TEXT/.test(x.innerHTML)) a.push(x.textContent);});
console.log(a);
```

Comment: no. Someone downvoted mine too. @Rajesh Check this. is it ok now?

Comment: I have removed my vote as it produces correct output, but OP is looking for regex.

Comment: ah. is that you. Thanks. I appreciate downvotes with comments. But I really hate people who downvote without any comment. your comment make me improve my answer.

Comment: I think this is OP's problem _I have to find paragraphs (between p tags) that contain string "TEXT"._ @Rajesh

Comment: Yup. As said, *it produces correct output*, also glad to help in any way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to add a delimiter like (...) or {...} or /.../ or [...] So try it like this:

```
/<p>.*?(TEXT).*?<\/p>/
```

But as Barman pointed it out, this does not always stay within one paragraph. If you really want to only select 1 paragraph you need something like this:

```
(?:<p |<p>)(?:(?!\/p>).|\n)*(TEXT).*?<\/p>
```

- `(?:<p |<p>)` Starts with `<p`  or `<p>` and `?:` in the beginning means "do not capture this in output"
- `(?:(?!\/p>).|\n)*` Any **character or newline** `.|\n` except a closing `/p>`  and `?:` in the beginning means "do not capture this in output"
- `(TEXT)` The word TEXT of course
- `.*?` any character with lazy quantifier "?" `.*?` to stop on the shortest match (before we have a `</p>`
- `<\/p>` And must end with closing `</p>` tag

And this one allows multiline text too!

Comment: This will match also the first paragraph in given text (first paragraph doesn't contain "TEXT")

Comment: This doesn't limit the match to a single paragraph.

Comment: You are totally right, I updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this:

- Create a regex to get all groups
- Loop over these regex to check for necessary search key and filter out the matches.

```js
var str = "<p>1 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>2 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>3 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p><p>4 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla TEXT bla</p><p>5 bla bla <em>bla</em> bla bla</p>";

var groupRegex = /(?:^|<p>)(.*?)(?:<\/p>|$)/g;
var searchRegex = /text/i
var groups = str.match(groupRegex);

var result = groups.filter(function(s){ return searchRegex.test(s) })

console.log(result)
```