# How to use regex to match paragraphs containing a specific word?

Tags: regex

I tried the answer of this post [Regex. Find paragraph containing some word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134425/regex-find-paragraph-containing-some-word), in my case that would be

```
((?!\n\n).)*(cat)
```

, but this don't work.

---

How can I use PCRE2 regular expressions (PHP >= 7.3) to match all paragraphs in my text that contain the word "cat", where each paragraph is separated by two consecutive line breaks (It is allowed to have one line break in a paragraph but not two)?

For example, if the input text is as follow

```
Paragraph 1 wepfowfpo
fww efwf

Paragraph 2 wefwf32321
!@d r33tcat54, 333!..

Paragraph 3 4t4t022
-`121231ere3r3cat342232
$ 4t0g cat rdwd203  
$$333

Paragraph 4 222cocdo3
```

Then the desired ouput is

```
Paragraph 3 4t4t022
-`121231ere3r3cat342232
$ 4t0g cat rdwd203  
$$333
```

I tried to use something like `\n\n.*(?=cat)cat.*\n\n`, but this match only those lines contain "cat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [splitting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string into paragraphs and [matching](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) those containing `cat`.

```
preg_grep('/\bcat\b/i', explode("\n\n", $str));
```

[See this PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##TY/BasMwEETv@xWbYLANbmLtqqektMce/QGG1LEkJ1CsZSNQ/95VT8113syDkZts2/l9@BwAqkdSfMN6mHRadJIbGsxeQsxBIoSc0YccAP45FV4iJiYDuw@HypzmKb3aDpl5dzg8txltsqkngpcvQ4bYePWsXAZsqTigKo1@wRKguuyoZ0SoqqJ69lgkojnOLnJ9AhC9r@mijahfLot6aerjeC2O8Xq8153/ke/ofLMf13Hdd/j3sm3b07b9Ag) - The [word bundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` prevents from matching `tcat5`.

---

If you can't use PHP functions, following a regex-only idea for [`(?m)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) *multiline* mode.

```
^(?:.+\n)*.*?\bcat\b.*(?:\n.+)*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZGKy5N/1) - Further add `i` flag to *ignore case* (also [match e.g. `Cat`](https://regex101.com/r/0O9ig7/1)).

| regex | explained |
| --- | --- |
| `(?m)` | flag for *multiline mode* to make `^` match *line start* too |
| `^(?:.+\n)*` | at `^` start [repeat](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) the [`(?:` non capturing group `)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) `*` *any amount* of times, containing: `.+` [*greedily*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) match *one or more* chars up to `\n` newline - part that matches lines before (if available, use of [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) instead [non capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) can be more efficient here: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXLy5a/1)) |
| `.*?\bcat\b.*` | `.*?` matches *lazily* any characters up to `\bcat\b` (using [word bundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) `.*` rest of line |
| `(?:\n.+)*` | matches any remaining lines in the paragraph where `.+` prevents to skip over `\n\n` |